# Given joint density function $f(x,y) = \frac 1y\mathsf 1_{(0,y)}(x)\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(y)$, find $\mathbb P(X+Y>1/2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This question comes from Schaums probability and statistics 3rd ed, question 2.91 which is

> Given joint density function $f(x,y) = \frac 1y\mathsf 1_{(0,y)}(x)\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(y)$, find $\mathbb P(X+Y>1/2)$

The answer given in the back of the book is $\mathbb P(X+Y>1/2) = \frac12\log 2.$

Denoting $U=X+Y$ and using $g(u) = \int f_1(v)*f_2(u-v)\ \mathsf dv$ and assuming the limit for $U$ are $1/2 < u < 2$ (this may not be correct), will therefore integrate $g$ from $1/2$ to $2$ to calculate the answer:

$$g(u) = \int_0^u \left(1/(u-v)\right)\ \mathsf dv = -\log(u-v)\lvert_{v=0}^u$$ from 0 to u = ln(u)

To calculate  P(X+Y>1/2) in integrated g(u) from 1/2 to 2.

=  $\int_{1/2}^2$ ln u = u ln(u) - 1 from 1/2 to 2

=  2ln(2) - 1/2 ln (1/2)

My error probably lies in the limits but this is a guess.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The interval is $0<x<y<1$ which is the triangle $\triangle(0,0)(0,1)(1,1)$; that is the upper left half triangle of the unit square.

You want to measure the mass of this triangle above/right-of the line $Y=\tfrac 1 2 - X$ .   This intercepts the triangles edges at $(0,\tfrac 1 2)$ and $(\tfrac 1 4,\tfrac 14)$.   So $\triangle(0,0)(0,1/2)(1/4,1/4)$ is the area where we *don't* want to measure the probability mass.

So subtracting the measure over that area from the total ($1$) we have: $$\mathsf P(X+Y>\tfrac 1 2) = 1 - \int_0^{1/4}\int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y - \int_{1/4}^{1/2} \int_0^{1/2-y} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x \operatorname d y$$

---

Alternatively:

> $$\begin{align}\iint_{\Omega_{X,Y}} \tfrac 1 y \mathbf 1_{\max(0,1/2-y)<x<y<1}\operatorname d (x,y) & = \int_{1/4}^1 \tfrac 1 y \int_{\max(0,1/2-y)}^{y} \operatorname d x\operatorname d y \\[1ex] & = \int_{1/4}^1 \tfrac 1 y\cdot\min(y, 2y-1/2)\operatorname d y \\[1ex] & = \int_{1/4}^{1/2} 2-\frac{1}{2y} \operatorname d y + \int_{1/2}^1 \operatorname d y \\[1ex] & = 1 - \tfrac 1 2 \ln(2)\end{align}$$

**tl;dr**  By the way, it seems the solution in your book is actually for $\mathsf P(X+Y\leq 1/2)$

Comment: I was doing this too but I found the answer to be $1-{1\over2}log2$ which is not correct as well.

Comment: @cr001  No, that is the answer.

Comment: Okay so the answer provided in the book is wrong. It is probably good to put that in your solution as well.

Comment: @cr001 Fair enough.

Comment: This is most likely the case as  I have found numerous errors in this book

Comment: @GrahamKemp Isn't the original textbook solution correct? The unit triangle total area is (1/2) not 1, so the answer becomes (1/2)-log(2)/2 = (log2)/2

Comment: @User38 Nope. $~$ We are working with *probability measures*, not simply area. $~$ The total probability is $1$. $$\int_0^1\int_0^y \tfrac 1 y\operatorname d x\operatorname d y ~=~ 1$$  Measuring probability as a ratio of areas is permissable only when dealing with uniform distributions. $~$ This triangular support area does *not* have a uniform probability density.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks, I see now.